# Send User Form in Excel to another Workbook?

Tags: excel, forms

I am very new to VB coding and creating forms in Excel.  I have created a very simple form in Excel that now captures user data and saves to a sheet within the Form's workbook.  Is there a way to code the command button so that it will save the user data to separate workbook that is saved on a network server?

Comment: yes, it is. post the snippet of code that saves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is open other workbook and insert data, for example

```
Sub ExtractData()

Dim nwb As Workbook

Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("\\Your\Server\Path\YourFile.xlsx")

With nwb.Sheets(1)
    .Range("A1").Value = YourForm.Textbox1.Text
    .Range("B1").Value = YourForm.Textbox2.Text
    .Range("C1").Value = YourForm.Textbox3.Text
End With

nwb.Close True

End Sub
```

you can also use ADO to use Insert statement with TSQL, to create a connection [see this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007)